# java - Replace new line character by \n

Tags: java

I'm coding an IDE. Let's say I have the [Hello, World](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Hello,_World) Pascal program on a string:

```
String sourceCode = "program Hello;\nbegin\nwriteln ('Hello, world.');\nend.";
```

If I do `System.out.println(sourceCode);` the output shows:

```
program Hello;
begin
writeln ('Hello, world.');
end.
```

Great, but I want to show new lines as `\n`. I tried:

```
sourceCode = sourceCode.replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "\\n");
```

But then `System.out.println(sourceCode);` outputs:

```
program Hello;nbeginnwriteln ('Hello, world.');nend.
```

When I expected `\n` to be shown:

```
program Hello;\nbegin\nwriteln ('Hello, world.');\nend.
```

How can I achieve that? Full demo:

```
public class PrintPascalHelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sourceCode = "program Hello;\nbegin\nwriteln ('Hello, world.');\nend.";
        System.out.println(sourceCode);
        sourceCode = sourceCode.replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "\\n");
        System.out.println(sourceCode);
    }
}
```

I'm able to compile and run it using [Online Java IDE](https://www.compilejava.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `replaceAll` unless you are trying to use regular expressions. `replace` works fine.

```
sourceCode = sourceCode.replace("\n", "\\n");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It also works. I prefer it, because it is simpler and less verbose.

Answer (score 4):

You use `String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` that takes as first parameter a `String regex` and as second one a `String replacement`.
This method has some specificities about the replacement `String`. Especially, if it contains a `\` or a `$` , it may not be interpreted as a literal.

According to the  [`Matcher.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) specified used under the hood by [`String.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) :

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated
>   as references to captured subsequences as described above, and
>   **backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement
>   string**.

In your case, `sourceCode.replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "\\n")`  will escape the literal `n` character.

If you want to use `replaceAll()`, you should use a convoluted way such as :

```
sourceCode = sourceCode.replaceAll("\n", "\\\\n");
```

As you don't need to work with a regex, it makes more sense to use `String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` that replaces a `CharSequence` by another and `String` is an instance of `CharSequence`.
So you can invoke :

```
sourceCode = sourceCode.replace("\n", "\\n")
```

where now the `String replacement` is handled as a literal.

---

Note also that `System.lineSeparator()` makes sense as you write in a file outputstream where the new line characters are inevitably OS dependent.
The `\n` end-of-line contained in a `String` such as     `"program Hello;\nbegin\nwriteln ('Hello, world.');\nend.";` is not OS dependent.

For example on Windows, a JVM 8  handles indifferently the Windows new line characters (`\r\n`) and `\n` as you print them in the standard output.

This code on Windows :

```
String sourceCode = "program Hello;\r\nbegin\nwriteln ('Hello, world.');\r\nend.";
System.out.println(sourceCode);
```

produces indeed :

> program Hello;
>
> begin
>
> writeln ('Hello, world.');
>
> end.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! `sourceCode = sourceCode.replaceAll("\n", "\\\\n");` is what I was looking for.

Comment: I forgot to say, but `System.lineSeparator()` was one of the things I tried to solve the problem, without success, of course, because `System.lineSeparator()` returns `\n` on Linux. But firstly I used `"\n"`.

Answer (score 3):

Since [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()) is platform dependent, as per docs:

> On UNIX systems, it returns "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it returns "\r\n".

It will be better to use `\n` directly:

```
String sourceCode = "program Hello;\nbegin\nwriteln ('Hello, world.');\nend.";
System.out.println(sourceCode);
sourceCode = sourceCode.replaceAll("\n", "\\\\n");
System.out.println(sourceCode);
```

is going to display:

```
program Hello;
begin
writeln ('Hello, world.');
end.
program Hello;\nbegin\nwriteln ('Hello, world.');\nend.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing the code on windows machine then it will surely fail. As

```
System.lineSeparator()
```

will return "\r\n" on windows. And it will not match "\n" from your input string.

You need to change to below code

```
sourceCode = sourceCode.replaceAll("\n", "\\\\n");
```